# Grouping WHILE loop results

Tags: php, tags, while-loop, if-statement

At the moment I'm using a WHERE loop to display 2 columns of information in my database. Here's the code:

```
$sql2 = sprintf($rawsql2, mysql_real_escape_string($id));
$result2 = mysql_query($sql2);

/*These if & while statements decide whether or not the information should be displayed. If no results are returned from the query above then an alternative message is shown.*/

if (mysql_num_rows($result2) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        echo $row["open"] . "-" . $row["close"] . "<br/><br/>";
    }
}
else {
    echo "Error";
}
```

This outputs the following:

```
08:00:00-12:30:00

13:30:00-16:30:00

09:00:00-17:00:00

18:00:00-20:00:00

09:00:00-17:00:00

18:00:00-20:00:00

08:00:00-17:00:00

18:00:00-20:00:00

09:00:00-17:00:00

18:00:00-20:00:00
```

Now, what I need to do is group every 2 lines that are turned so instead it would look like:

```
08:00:00-12:30:00 13:30:00-16:30:00

09:00:00-17:00:00 18:00:00-20:00:00

09:00:00-17:00:00 18:00:00-20:00:00

08:00:00-17:00:00 18:00:00-20:00:00

09:00:00-17:00:00 18:00:00-20:00:00
```

Is this possible? Thanks for any help

edit: Thanks for all the answers everyone...I used Shakti's answer as it was the first one I saw but by the looks of it everyone's are pretty similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(mysql_num_rows($result2) > 0)
{
    $count=0;
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2, MYSQL_ASSOC))
    {    
        echo $row["open"] . "-" . $row["close"] ;
        if ($count % 2 !=0 )
        {
           echo  "<br/><br/>"; 
        } 
        $count++;    
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for the solution. -1 for the horrid, inconsistent formatting.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(mysql_num_rows($result2) > 0){
    $counter = 0;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
        echo $row["open"] . "-" . $row["close"] . " ";
        if(++$counter % 2 == 0){
          echo "<br/><br/>";
          $counter = 0;
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: That counter's going to run out eventually. Best change the value of `$counter` as you go.

Comment: @Tomalak: What are you talking about?  `$counter` gets incremented each iteration.

Comment: @Rocket: Your `$counter` variable increments forever. Eventually it could overflow, given enough rows in the recordset. It's messy coding. Instead, perform `% 2` to the variable itself so that it's only ever `0` or `1`.

Comment: @Tomalak: Unless he has 2,147,483,647 rows returned from the db query, I don't think it makes a difference.

Comment: @Rocket: He may do. Why take the chance? As I said, it's messy coding. There's simply _no need_ to take the risk.

Comment: The 2,147,483,647 rows would create an over 40GB file. I haven't seen anything as big.

Comment: @Michas: We have several at work (though we don't retrieve all rows at once, of course :D). It doesn't really matter what you or I have seen, though; perhaps in the future this will become the norm. Why on earth would you leave this _potential_ bug in, when it's just as easy to make your code 100% safe? It's ludicrous.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: The 40GB of data isn't something extraordinary. The 40GB of data in single file is.

Comment: @Michas: Yes, I know. Read the rest of my comment, too.

Comment: Tomalak - stop bringing this petty complaints to everyones answers.  the issue of integer overflow is so irrelevant to this question

Comment: This code is safe on 64-bit PHP. It should be quite safe on 32-bit PHP too. The number would be converted to 64-bit float. For about 10 years creating 40GB html files for browsers would be very insane.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$lines = 1;
if(mysql_num_rows($result2) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

        echo $row["open"] . "-" . $row["close"];
        echo (($lines%2 == 0)?"<br/><br/>":'');
        $lines++;

    }
} else {
        echo "Error";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $i=1;
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    if ($i == 1) {
      echo $row["open"] . "-" . $row["close"];
      $i++;
    } else {
      echo $row["open"] . "-" . $row["close"] . "<br /><br />";
      $i=1;
    }
```

Comment: You have a syntax error (extra `;`) and lots of code duplication.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($result2) { 
    $printTimes = function($r) {echo $row["open"] . "-" . $row["close"];};
    $newLine = false;
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)) 
    {
        $printTimes($row);
        echo $newLine ?  '<br /><br />' : ' ';
        $newLine = !$newLine;
    }
}
```

Comment: You've duplicated the MySQL access. That's a bit ew.

Comment: there is no MySQL access in my code.  you refer to how i used to have two fetches?  i decided i liked this better, but i dont see anything wrong with that anyway

Comment: @jon_darkstar: Correct. You had two fetches, retrieving from a MySQL recordset. How that amounts to "no MySQL access" is anyone's guess...

Comment: because the access is in `mysql_query`.  everything after that is just using the resource object returned from the query

Comment: @jon_darkstar: Yes, you're accessing the resource object. Nitpick all you like about which function you're calling, you were still doing two identical function calls for no reason.

Comment: i initially considered looping half as many times and calling a function twice instead of once in each loop.  i decided against it, but reserve the right todo so.  i maintain that its not particularly bad form anyhow and your comment was silly particular in light of actual errors in your own code.

Comment: @jon_darkstar: Please point out "actual errors" in my code. There are, in fact, none.

Answer (score 0):

My version of code.

```
    $sql2 = sprintf($rawsql2, mysql_real_escape_string($id));
    $result2 = mysql_query($sql2);

    if(mysql_num_rows($result2) > 0) {
        while (true) {
            $row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result2, MYSQL_ASSOC);
            $row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2, MYSQL_ASSOC);
            if (!($row1 and $row2)) break;
            echo $row1["open"] . "-" . $row1["close"] . " ";
            echo $row2["open"] . "-" . $row2["close"] . "<br/><br/>";
        }
    } else {
        echo "Error";
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$sql2 = sprintf($rawsql2, mysql_real_escape_string($id));

$result2 = mysql_query($sql2);

/*These if & while statements decide whether or not the information should be displayed. If no results are returned from the query above then an alternative message is shown.*/
int row_count=mysql_num_rows($result2)
if(row_count > 0) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        row_count--;
        echo $row["open"] . "-" . $row["close"] ;
        if(row_count > 0 && ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
          row_count--;   
          echo $row["open"] . "-" . $row["close"] ;
         }
        "<br/><br/>"


    }
} else {
        echo "Error";
}
```

should do it, u may need to catch if there is an odd number

Comment: @Steven: What's the point of checking `mysql_num_rows($result2)` _again_?

Comment: @Tomalak, why fetch an array if there is no arrays left to fetch?
But you are right it is not needed. In that regard the first one is not even needed at the start.

Comment: @Steven: I think you misunderstand what `mysql_num_rows` does. The second one does exactly what the first one does. So whilst you're right that the first one is required, if it _is_ used then the second is even more redundant.

Comment: @Tomalak, does it not return the current number of rows left? so after each mysql_fetch_array it's value decreases. Or does it return the number of rows initially returned? Either way I feel that a counter would be better,to relieve server load, even if it is only one request

Comment: @Steven: Nope. It's the number of rows in the recordset, no matter where you are in iterating that recordset. It's not like the rows cease to exist when you read them out; you can seek to any point in the recordset whenever you like. Going forwards one at a time is just the most common use case. (And I agree, a counter is a much better idea.)

Answer (score -2):

Output `<br/><br/>` only on *every other* iteration of the loop. (BTW, a `<p>` or `<ul>` or `<div>` would be more semantic.)

```
$counter = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

    echo $row["open"] . "-" . $row["close"] . " ";

    // Break line after every two items
    $counter = ($counter + 1) % 2;
    if ($counter == 0)
        echo "<br/><br/>";
}
```

Comment: `$counter` doesnt count anything.  it is a wasteful version of a toggle.  `num_rows` command is pointless - there is still an error if `$result2` is false instead of resource, and if it is a proper resource with zero lines the `while` body is never going to run anyway

Comment: @jon_darkstar: It counts the number of rows modulo 2. How is it "wasteful"? It _is_ a toggle. If you're suggesting that I'm "wasting space" by using an integer rather than a boolean, then my response is that I let PHP worry about micro-optimisations like that. Three bytes, even if used, is not going to kill anyone.

Comment: you want to nitpick first, i can nitpick too.  i know the performance difference is unimportant, but the name still sucks

Comment: @jon_darkstar: I'm not nitpicking at all. I'm certainly not downvoting anybody.

Comment: and your welcome for suggestion concerning `num_rows`, as i see you have taken it

Comment: @jon_darkstar: What suggestion?

Comment: despite the fact that you are very critical of unnecessary `mysql` function calls you had wrapped everything in the pointless `mysql_num_rows` conditional

Comment: hah oops maybe you havent.  dont see an `edit` now that i look at it

Comment: @jon_darkstar: Oh, I see that you have now edited your initial comment to mirror that I removed the pointless `mysql_num_rows()` check. I had initially kept it in to maintain proximity to the OP's original code (_I_ didn't wrap anything), but changed my mind in light of some other answers that seemed to be even _duplicating_ the check.

Comment: you have put petty comments on almost every answer here.  if you can dish it out then learn how to take it.  i never had `mysql_num_rows` in my answer, and i indicated that it was pointless before you made any mention of it or removed it from your answer.  similarly on Rocket's answer you bickered over the possibility of `$counter` overflowing when it should be a moot point.  it is simply a parity boolean and should be treated as such. good day sir

Comment: @jon_darkstar: No, I left criticism of real issues. I didn't downvote anybody. You have downvoted a perfectly functional, valid answer on the basis of the perceived (and usually optimised-out) waste of a whole three bytes. Who's petty now? Conversation over..

Comment: i dont care about the 3 bytes (or the unnecessary arithmetic operations).  you have a poorly named variable that is called `counter` but doesnt count, and it is less readable than it could be.  you dont get to declare conversations over

Comment: @jon_darkstar: No, I already responded to that. It _does_ count. It counts modulo 2. Read up on [modulo arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic). And I get to do whatever I like, thankyou very much.

Comment: Why has this been downvoted? It's a working, correct solution.